# Inserted row missing after application restarts

Tags: android, ormlite

I am using ORMLite to do an insertion using the code below:

```
protected void registerUser(EditText fullName, EditText email, EditText mobile, EditText username, EditText password) {
        //Perform DB Call to Insert Records                 
        User user = new User();
        user.setFullName(fullName.getText().toString());
        user.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
        user.setMobile(mobile.getText().toString());
        user.setUsername(username.getText().toString());
        user.setPassword(password.getText().toString());

        DBManager.getInstance().addUser(user);
    }
```

But after restarting the application, the above record is missing and my login fails.
I use the following code to authenticate and it works for existing records.

```
public boolean login(String username, String password) {
    boolean validLogin = false;
    try {           
        QueryBuilder<User, Integer> qb = getHelper().getUserDao().queryBuilder();           
        qb.where().eq("username", username).and().eq("password", password);         
        PreparedQuery<User> pq = qb.prepare();
        User user = getHelper().getUserDao().queryForFirst(pq);    
        if(user!=null){
            validLogin = true;
        }           
    } catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return validLogin;
}
```

In my Helper class, I am creating table only when not available.

```
TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource, User.class);
```

How does ORMLite handle the commit operations? Do we have to manually commit? Please suggest If i am missing something as I am new to Android and ORMLite.

Comment: For more information, I am using the Android Database.

Comment: Can you show the "addUser(...)" method?  That's what's doing the DB operation.

Comment: This is the code for addUser() 
 public void addUser(User user) {
  try {
   getHelper().getUserDao().create(user);
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Comment: I wrote a new method commit() yesterday, which is setting the setAutoCommit(true) and is working now. But, this method is depricated.

 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 public void commit() throws SQLException {
  getHelper().getUserDao().setAutoCommit(true);  
 }
 Is this approach better?

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, don't forget to +1 it and accept it (click the check-mark). See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

After some more information was provided in the comments, the problem seems to be that auto-commit had been disabled either by calling `dao.setAutoCommit(false)` or by starting a transaction that was never finished or was rolled back.

Using a try/finally pattern like the following is recommended.

```
try {
   dao.setAutoCommit(false);
   ...
   ...
 } finally {
   dao.setAutoCommit(true);
   dao.commit();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Apologies for the delayed response, was away for quite sometime.